# How to archive live streaming in Azure Media Service

Tags: azure-media-services

I am trying to use Azure Media service to do the 7x24 live streaming and also try to persist the streamed video. In the document it said the Live Output can set the archiveWindowLength upto 25 hours for VOD. But not really able to persist the whole streamed videos.

Any idea about how to achieve it. I am quite new in this area. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please add some more details. What error are you having?

Comment: How long of an archive do you plan to create? Several days long? Months long?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DVR window length for a single Liveoutput is 25 hours.  The reason for the 25 hours is to provide a 1 hour overlap for you to switch to a second Liveoutput with a new Asset underneath.

Typically how i set this up is to have an Azure Function and Logic App running with a timer to ping-poing between two LiveOutputs. You have to create a new LiveOutput with a new Asset. 
Think of LiveOutputs as "tape recorders" and the Asset is the "tape".  You have to swap between tape recorders and switch tapes ever xx-hours.

You do not necessarily have to wait a full 25 hours though. I actually recommend not doing that because of the size of the manifest gets really huge.  Sometimes loading such a large HLS or DASH manifest on a client can really mess with memory and cause some bad things to happen.  So, you could consider doing the ping-pong between your "tape recorders" every 1 hour.

If you wish to "publish" the live event to your audience with a smaller DVR window (say 10 minutes or 30 minutes) you could additionally create a 3rd LiveOutput and Asset and leave that one set to a DVR window of 30 minutes and leave it running forever.